# Jquery forward slashes are being replaced by spaces within tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm receiving urls within a view, and I'm using JQuery to assign those urls to some html elements.. I'm reading the urls in the view and I'm seeing that the forward slashes are still there.. But on the page output they are being replaced by spaces...
This my code:

```
    $('#someId').append("<div class='request-quote__dropdown'>
<div class='request-quote__dropdown-image' 
style='background-image: url('"+element.parent.PictureUrl+"');'>
</div></div>")
```

So the value that `element.parent.PictureUrl` contains is `"https://localhost:44390/images/thumbs/0000570_ackerman_schoendorf_scales_for_parent_evaluation_of_custody_aspect_100.jpeg"` I'm reading it using `Json.stringify()`. But the image is not rendering on the page and when I inspect the element it look like this:

```
        <div class="request-quote__dropdown-image" 
style="background-image: url(" https:="" localhost:44390="" images="" 
thumbs=""     0000570_ackerman_schoendorf_scales_for_parent_evaluation_of_custody_aspect_100.jpeg');'=""></div>
```

I've tried this way too but still the same results...

```
`<div class='request-quote__dropdown-image' style='background-image: url('${element.parent.PictureUrl}');'></div>`
```

I'm working with json, I've read that json prevent the use of forward slashes within html elements.. not sure why.. How can I keep the forward slashes? They are necessary to display the images on the page..

**UPDATE:**
The relevant `Json` looks like this:

```
     {"parent":{"Name":"Ackerman-Schoendorf Scales for Parent Evaluation of
 Custody™ (ASPECT™)","Author":"Marc Y.Heiks, PhD and Kathleen Schand, 
PsyD","Quantities":null,"Id":2666,"PictureUrl":"https://localhost:44390/images
/thumbs/0000570_ackerman_schoendorf_scales_for_parent_evaluation_of_custody_aspect_100.jpeg"},
```

Comment: You need to provide your JSON.  Also, I don't understand why you would use `Json.stringify()` as it's intended use is to *serialize* not *deserialize* (`Json.Parse()`).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I updated my question, posted some Json in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this

```
style='background-image: url('"
```

You have a single quote around the background image css, and then a single quote around the url. That is going to cause it to terminate the style tag instantly after "url(". Everything after that is registered as a new attribute, and that just results in the bizarre html where the image name seems to be interpreted as an attribute.

Try "\" instead of the single quotes around the url. If that doesn't work, try rearranging what uses single quotes, double quotes, and escaped quotes until it generates the correct html. I've had this exact problem. That has always resolved it.

After edit:

```
 $('#someId').append("<div class='request-quote__dropdown'>
<div class='request-quote__dropdown-image' 
style='background-image: url(\""+element.parent.PictureUrl+"\");'>
</div></div>")
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, I didn't really use this solution because I changed my syntax to use Template Strings: https://jack.ofspades.com/multiline-strings-in-es6-javascript/ . But I removed the single quote and then it worked: style='background-image: url(${element.parent.PictureUrl});'